# appcompat v7 23 - Menu Item with app:showAsAction="withText|always" doesn't display title

Tags: android, android-menu

I have a menu item, with icon and text. I am using Appcompat v7 library. The menu item is not displaying text, even when showAsAction is set to withText|always or vice-versa.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_registration_next"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="Next"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I have tried these combinations for showAsAction.

```
always|withText
withText|always
ifRoom|withText
```

The toolbar only shows the icon, but not the title. How can i show both title and icon? Please look at the image below:

[image]

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I believe it's either text or icon with a menu xml. If you want both, you need a custom layout in the toolbar

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action bar/toolbar implementations consider `withText` to be a request, not a command. They will decide whether to show the text on whether or not there is sufficient room for it. In this case, `appcompat-v7` apparently thinks that there is not enough room. If you try rotating this device to landscape, or testing on a tablet, you should see the title show up, if you have `withText` as part of your `app:showAsAction` attribute.

Comment: Okie.. Understood. I can see it in landscape mode. Is there a workaround (without creating a view in toolbar) where i force to make both text and icon visible in portrait mode, since i am only having one menu item.

Comment: @VamsiChalla: Not that I am aware of. Bear in mind that if you are supporting multiple languages, while you may have room for the text in some languages, you may not in others. I recommend simply allowing the action bar/toolbar implementation to make the decision.